# How to use the date command on Mac OS to get the current day of the week?

Tags: macos, date, terminal

I would like to use the date command on a Mac to find out the day corresponding to a certain date.

On Debian, the command below works:

```
date --date "Jul 20 1999" +%A
```

But the same command does not work when I run it on macOS' terminal.

What can be an alternative to achieve the output of the above command on a Mac?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This works:

```
date -j -vJulm -v20d -v1999y '+%A'
```

According to the OSX **`date`** [*manual page*](https://www.unix.com/man-page/mojave/1/date/) (alternate [*link*](https://manp.gs/mac/1/date)):

> **`-v`**
> Adjust (i.e., take the current date and display the result of the adjustment; not actually set
> the date) the second, minute, hour, month day, week day, month or year according to *val*.  If
> *val* is preceded with a plus or minus sign, the date is adjusted forwards or backwards according
> to the remaining string, otherwise the relevant part of the date is set.  The date can be
> adjusted as many times as required using these flags.

Comment: The link is dead and was never recorded on archive.org. https://ss64.com/osx/date.html does not list the `-v` option, but https://www.unix.com/man-page/mojave/1/date/ does.

Answer (score 3):

Another way that may work:

```
date -j -f "%b %d %Y" "Jul 20 1999" "+%A"
```

It uses the format:

```
date -j -f "input_format" "datestring" "output_format"
```

where

- `-j`

  - need to use it to tell `date` not to set the time and to use the `-f` flag which allows you to parse a date string and format it however you want
  - **Man Page**

    - "Do not try to set the date.  This allows you to use the -f flag in addition to the + option to convert one date format to another."
- `-f`

  - this allows you to define the format
  - **Man Page**

    - "Use input_fmt as the format string to parse the new_date provided rather than using the default [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss] format.  Parsing is done using strptime(3)."

Some formatting options

- `%b` for abbreviated Month name: Jul
- `%B` for full Month name: July
- `%a` for abbreviated weekday name: Tue
- `%A` for full weekday name: Tuesday
- `%d` for day of month: 20
- `%Y` for 4 character year: 1999

  - **Man Page**

    - "year.  This is normally at least four characters, but it may be
      more.  Year ‘0000’ precedes year ‘0001’, and year ‘-001’ precedes
      year ‘0000’."

Comment: It should be noted perhaps that this requires the locale to be set so it matches the abbreviated month names.