# Get specific day of week of the upcoming Canada day on Linux

Tags: linux, macos

How to use `cal` command to add the calendar of next July to the end of the file, for example, myfile, and what day of the week the upcoming Canada Day fall on?

So far I just have this command:

```
cal July 2017 >> myfile
```

I feel like I am not doing it correct and I don't know which command to use, to find the day of the week for specific date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this command:

```
cal 7 2017 >> file
```

The output is:

```
     July 2017
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
                   1
 2  3  4  5  6  7  8
 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20 21 22
23 24 25 26 27 28 29
30 31
```

You can find out day of week of a particular day with the GNU `date` command:

```
date -d"2017-07-01"              # what day of week is Canada Day this year?
=> Sat Jul  1 00:00:00 UTC 2017
```

If you just want the week day, then:

```
date -d"2017-07-01" +%A
=> Saturday
```

You can check more about these commands with `man cal` or `man date`.

On a Mac, you could do this:

```
date -j -vJulm -v1d -v2017y +%A
```

See more on this post: [date command on Mac OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34122471/date-command-on-mac-os)

Comment: Is there any command that finds a day of the week for this day?

Comment: for some reason it gives me this output

Comment: usage: date [-jnu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]

Comment: What version of OS are you using?  If you are on a Mac, please see the updated answer.